# How can I create a basic ckeditor?

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor, wysiwyg, fckeditor

I'm using ckeditor in my website and I want a simple editor for one of the textareas, my question is how can I do that ? (I need bold ,italic, undeline - some really basic things)

Comment: It's all in the [docs](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_installation)

Comment: But how the HTML source would be look like?

Comment: I'm sorry Nave, but it really is all in the docs. Have a read of all the subsections on the left of the page I linked to. If you can't understand them, then come back and ask a specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can configure ckeditor to only show some of the styling options instead of the entire menu by overriding the "toolbar" attribute.

CkEditor can be customized to show only certain amount of styling options.

http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Toolbar

Comment: Thanks, but how the html source will be? (Can you pleas write it here) -I don't know this very well...

Comment: It will not be in the html source, but rather the javascript file for CkEditor unless you are using CkEditor through a framework, like Primefaces Extensions. [link] http://fractalsoft.net/primeext-showcase-mojarra/views/ckEditor.jsf . If you are not using a framework or the framework doesn't support modifying the toolbar than you will have to modify the js file.